# Solar panels without sunlight?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm running FTB direwolf20 and I use a lot of solar alloys. Is there any way of providing "fake" sunlight? Torches and glowstone don't seem to help keep my panels up during night.

Hybrid panels are still a bit too expensive for me, so if there is another solution I'd be thrilled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, regular solar panels require direct line of sight (or glass blocks) to the sky.

Hybrid panels also require line of sight to the sky but will generate partial power during the night.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cover block, they will count as transparent blocks.

Answer (score -1):

they are called SOLAR panels for a reason as in using the sun

Comment: Real life terminology is not always 100% correctly used in video games.